# caching angular2 Html pages and its ngOnInit method

Tags: angular

I am working on tabs in my angular2 web app.I have three tabs containing user profile information.

1st Tab contain user personal info for that data I am calling an API

2nd Tab contain user subscription info that is also coming form API

But problem I am facing is when I change the tab my api are getting called every time.which is not proper.

I have use both this

```
.share() and .cache()
```

method and also written my code in ngOnInit function but still the same my api's are getting called whenever I change the tab.
Can anyone please help me out to cache the view or its ngOnInit method.

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. Currently there is not enough information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late.
But a easy way to keep a cache from your component during all the life-cycle of a Angular2 app is using a storage variable in your service.

```js
private myObject:any; 
  
  constructor(private _dataService: DataServiceService) { 
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    //Recover Cache from the servicies
    // IF cache==null THEN getAPI
    // ELSE get chache from the service
   if(this._dataService.storage["myObject"] == null){
      this.getMyObject(); 
    }else{
      this.myObject = this._dataService.storage["myObject"];
    }
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    // STORE CACHE in the service BEFORE DESTROY the COMPOMENT
    this._dataService.storage["myObject"] == null ? this._dataService.storage["myObject"] = this.myObject : this.myObject = this._dataService.storage["myObject"];
  }
  getMyObject(){
    
    this._dataService.getAPI("YOURAPI").subscribe(
        (p:any)=>this.myObject = p,
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

```js
   public storage;

   constructor(private http: Http) {
     this.storage ={};
   }
```

So, I assume that you cont want to call the API call every time you change between components, It works for me.